# Why is the derivative of a quadratic invariant zero if the matrix is symmetric?

Tags: matrices, runge-kutta-methods, invariance

I was shown a proof in class, where it was said that all Runge-Kutta methods preserve the quadratic invariant $$I(y) = y^TCy \quad ,$$ where $C$ is a quadratic symmetric matrix, under the condition $$b_i a_{ij} + b_j a_{ji} - b_ib_j = 0 \quad .$$ In general I understood the form of the prove, however I am struggling with why $$\frac{d}{dt}I(y) = 2y^TCf(y) = 0 \quad, $$ holds and is zero as per my professor. If I try to perform the same step I arrive at the following form $$\frac{d}{dt}I(y) = (C+C^T)y  \quad, $$ where I do not see why it would be zero for a symmetric matrix C.

I would appreciate if someone could show me where I went wrong and especially why the statement of my professor is true. If any more of the underlying proof is necessary to show I can add it.

Comment: What is the connection between relationship $b_i a_{ij} + b_j a_{ji} - b_ib_j = 0$ and this issue ? What are the corresponding matrix $A$ and vector $B$ ? Have you changed your notations ? $A=C$ and $B=y$ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie For $b_i a_{ij} + b_j a_{ji} - b_ib_j = 0$ the $b$ and $a$ are the coefficients of the Runge-Kutta methods. But as this is for a general s-step RK method I don't know the corresponding Butcher tableau. $A$ and $C$ as well as $B$ and $y$ should be "unrelated".

Comment: Is the matrix $C$ related to the $c_i=\sum_ja_{ij}$ or arbitrary? One might better use $M$ or another unrelated letter.

Comment: You should made reference in your text to the Butcher tableaux as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question seems not so much to be about Runge-Kutta methods but about the derivative of quadratic forms. There you get by the product rule
$$
\frac{d}{dt}I(y(t))=\frac{d}{dt}y(t)^TCy(t)=\dot y(t)^TCy(t)+y(t)^TC\dot y(t)
$$
Now the terms are scalars, thus invariant under transposition, apply that to the first term
$$
=y(t)^T(C^T+C)\dot y(t)
$$
and then apply the symmetry of $C$ to get $C^T+C=2C$.

That the derivative of a constant is zero is trivial, the last step then is to insert $\dot y(t)=f(y(t))$.

Comment: First off all, thank you, this answers my initial question. However, I wonder then why is the initial proof restricted to symmetric matrices? Wouldn't the statement $ y(t)^T(C^T+C)\dot y(t) = 0 $ also hold true for every matrix, as I can decompose some quadratic generic matrix $A$ into $A_{sym} + A_{skewsym}$ and for skew-symmetric matrices $B^T = -B$ ?

Comment: I'm not sure at the moment. You can represent every quadratic form with a symmetric matrix, so this might indeed only be a question of convenient notation.